# JQuery click/trigger not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

there is a lot of similiar questions, but I have a problem that I want to trigger event which is already set. The code on the page is:

```
<a class="btn-medium btn-primary TradeCurrencyModalBtn">Start</a>
```

I used Visual Event plugin and it showed this:
[image]

As you can see, the button has his own function set.

But my code does nothing:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("a.btn-medium btn-primary TradeCurrencyModalBtn").trigger("click");
});
```

When I click on *trigger event* (in the picture), it triggers perfectly.
This is what I tried (none of them working):

```
$("a.btn-medium btn-primary TradeCurrencyModalBtn")[0].trigger("click");

$("a.btn-medium btn-primary TradeCurrencyModalBtn")[0].click();

$("a.btn-medium btn-primary TradeCurrencyModalBtn").click();
```

I even tried deleting all other elements, still not triggering from my code. Any ideas?
I have implemented the latest JQuery.

Comment: it's possible jQuery is stopping event propagation through that click event handler. Can you try removing the already existing handler and just attach your own, as a test? [this](http://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/) might be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your selector is wrong.

do like this:

```
$("a.btn-medium.btn-primary.TradeCurrencyModalBtn").trigger("click"); 
// tirgger click for anchor tag which has class btn-medium  btn-primary TradeCurrencyModalBtn
```

as you are trying to fire click for anchor which has all these classes.

Comment: Oh how could I be so dumb... Thanks!